# Crossbrowser issue - jquery don't show first entry of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this selectbox in a searchform:

```
<select name="searchFor" id="searchFor">
 <option name="option0" value="Choice">Pick one</option>
 <option name="option1" value="person">Person</option>
 <option name="option2" value="title">Title</option>
</select>
```

Because the top option shouldn't be selectable, I remove it using JQuery:

```
$("#searchFor").focus(function() {
  $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
});
```

Works like a charm except offcourse for Internet Explorer.
In All browsers the option0 is removed when the select-tag is selected.
In IE the option only gets removed after one of the options gets selected. which makes you always choose the wrong one.
The action is repeated as well untill all of the options are gone.

Anyone got an idea on how to get this working in IE?

So the top-option should be removed from a select-tag when the select gets activated.

cheers

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't keep removing the first option on every single focus in other browsers ?

Comment: What are you looking for? Your code doesn't make much sense here

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that removes the first option (option0) from the select, when it gets selected. It should do so only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unbind the focus event like this

```
$("#searchFor").on('change',function() {
  $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
  $(this).off('change');
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KJG9V/1/)

Comment: still having the same problem. In IE the option0 is removed after you select an option, not when you select the select-list. When this happens it selects the option under the one you wanted. So if you want to select option1 it gives you option2. (only in IE)
url: http://www.hetfilmhuis.be

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, use "focusin" event and one() function to make the event handler run only once.

```
$("#searchFor").one("focusin", function() {
  $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();
});
```